# Guile scheme cond ERROR: Wrong type to apply: (1 2 3 4)

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

I am playing with scheme and puzzled in to this crazy issue

```
(define func((lambda N lst)
          (if(eq? N 0) 0 (+ (car lst) 2))))
```

calling function

```
(func 2 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

got following error when I called function

```
ERROR: In procedure (1 2 3 4):
ERROR: Wrong type to apply: (1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: The error doesn't match the code at all. How you have written `func` it will not even bind `func` since it fails to compile. The error you are getting seems to suggest you are calling `lst` like `(lst)`, perhaps with more arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a parenthesis issue. It happens quite a lot when beginning with scheme.

I recommend that you **indent your code correctly**, it will make it more **readable** and much **less error prone**.

```
(define func
  (lambda (N lst)
    (if (eq? N 0)         
        0 
        (+ (car lst) 2))))
```

The extra () you had was translated to a [function call](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html)